# How can I make my divs have an automatic "100% of its parent" height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been working on a table made from scratch using jQuery, the only problem is, I can't be able to make the `.th`s and `td`s fill up the whole `.tr` without screwing up my table.

**How it should be:**

```
| head |      |
| erla | head | When the first th's text it too big  it should expand both ths
|_laha_|______|
| cell | cell |
| cell | cell |
| cell | cell |
| cell | cell |
```

**The problem:**

```
| head | head |
| erla |------| When the first th's text it too big it doesn't expand both ths
|_laha_|      |
| cell | cell |
| cell | cell |
| cell | cell |
| cell | cell |
```

```js
$.fn.scrollify = function() {
  //Set up header
  $(this.selector + ' .thead .tr .th').width(($(this.selector + ' .thead').innerWidth() / $(this.selector + ' .thead .tr .th').length) - (19 / $(this.selector + ' .thead .tr .th').length));

  //Set up body
  $(this.selector + ' .tbody').width($(this.selector + ' .tbody').outerWidth());
  $(this.selector + ' .tbody').height($(this).height() - $(this.selector + " .thead").outerHeight());
  $(this.selector + ' .tbody .tr .td').width((($(this.selector + ' .thead').innerWidth() / $(this.selector + ' .thead .tr .th').length)) - (19 / $(this.selector + ' .thead .tr .th').length));
};

$(".table").scrollify();
```

```css
.td,
.th {
  display: inline-table;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
}
.tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.table {
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 -5px -1px 0;
}
.td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 -5px -1px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>smartSystem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="myTable">

    <div class="table">

      <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="th">Headerasdasdasdasdasd</div>
          <div class="th">Header</div>
          <div class="th">Header</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tbody">
        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="tr">
          <div class="td">Headerasdasdasd</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
          <div class="td">Header</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If this is tabular data, why not just use a table?  Otherwise you can remove the thead and tbody divs, give the following styles: `table {display:table;} tr {display:table-row;} td {display:table-cell;}`

Comment: That's not the point, I don't want use table

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, take a look at bootstrap, you'll find what you want without having manipulating the DOM yourself. Otherwise try set the th height to 100%

Comment: It's about time we reinvented the wheel. ok ok, I get you "don't want to use a table", fair enough but why don't you want to use a table when it's designed to do exactly what you're after?

Comment: add some height to the (.td, .th) class  ( height: 39px;) -- at the moment you have auto and that obviously doesnt work -- you can automate that with Js and record the biggest cell height dynamically, and change the others to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using display: table-cell

```
.td, .th {
   display: table-cell;
   word-break: break-all;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   height: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07krv81m/

Comment: Thanks dude, you helped me a lot +1

Comment: @Mr. Derpinthoughton --   dont celebrate too quickly, that breaks the table if the header is larger -- https://jsfiddle.net/u77tyon7/ ;)

Comment: @Tasos How is that broken? It maybe do with vertical-align: middle but looks okay to me.

Comment: Your code is fine, but the scrolling doesnt work from the link above, at least on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `div`s behave like a table using the following:

```css
.table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  display: table;
  width:300px;
}
.thead {
  display:table-header-group;
}
.tbody {
  display:table-row-group;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td,
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align:middle;
  /* this is just for example */
  width: 100px;    
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">Headerasdasdasdasdasd</div>
      <div class="th">Header</div>
      <div class="th">Header</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Headerasdasdasd</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
      <div class="td">Header</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Semantically speaking though, if this is tabular data, you should use an actual table, then you can give scope to your table headings

Comment: Or `.tbody`, etc. could have `display: table-header-group | table-row-group`.

Comment: Can I scroll down your tbody without scrolling the thead?